# remove ripple and its background from angular material 16 completely

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular 16 + material 16. I dont want the ripple and also its background on mouse hover.

How can I do that.

I tried this, but no effet.

```
const globalRippleConfig: RippleGlobalOptions = {
  disabled: true,
  animation: {
    enterDuration: 0,
    exitDuration: 0
  }
};
```

And used in providers like this.

```
providers: [
    // {provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {disabled: true}},
    {provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: globalRippleConfig}
  ]
```

Please help.